# "warning: passing floating-point values to sym is dangerous" with Octave ranges

Tags: range, octave, symbolic-math

I am trying to use `ellipticF`, inside a user defined function `test_ellipticF`, then integrate the function, and plot the result, so I would need to pass a range to `test_ellipticF` and within it to `ellipticF`.
I put together a (MCVE) script `test_integrals` to test how to use `ellipticF` inside a user defined function and pass a range, using "trick" `sym( , 'f')` shown [here](https://octave.discourse.group/t/how-to-change-code-to-avoid-the-warning-from-floating-point-and-symbolic/1565/2) to remove the warning, and deferring the integration.

```
function eF = test_ellipticF(phi, m)
    % Solution to "warning: passing floating-point values to sym is dangerous"
    %  from https://octave.discourse.group/t/how-to-change-code-to-avoid-the-warning-from-floating-point-and-symbolic/1565/2
    eF = ellipticF(sym(phi, 'f'), sym(m, 'f'));
    return
endfunction

eF = test_ellipticF(pi/4, 1)            % Warning removed
eF = test_ellipticF(pi/4, 0.9:0.1:1)    % Warning not removed
```

The trick worked well for removing the warning in many cases, but passing a range to `sym` is immune to it.

```
>> test_integrals

eF = (sym)

   /884279719003555 | \
  F|----------------|1|
   \1125899906842624| /

warning: passing floating-point values to sym is dangerous, see "help sym"
warning: called from
    double_to_sym_heuristic at line 50 column 7
    sym at line 379 column 13
    numeric_array_to_sym at line 36 column 16
    sym at line 359 column 7
    test_ellipticF at line 175 column 11
    test_integrals at line 189 column 4

eF = (sym 1x2 matrix)

  [ /884279719003555 |    \   /884279719003555 | \]
  [F|----------------|9/10|  F|----------------|1|]
  [ \1125899906842624|    /   \1125899906842624| /]
```

Upon further testing, I confirmed that the combination of `sym( , 'f')` and ranges produces the warning, prior to any use of a user defined function or `ellipticF`

```
>> sym(0.9:0.1:1, 'f')
warning: passing floating-point values to sym is dangerous, see "help sym"
warning: called from
    double_to_sym_heuristic at line 50 column 7
    sym at line 379 column 13
    numeric_array_to_sym at line 36 column 16
    sym at line 359 column 7

ans = (sym) [9/10  1]  (1x2 matrix)
```

**How can I solve this?**

I guess I could use `for` loops, but I expect to have a more concise solution, if possible.

I foresee that when solving this, the full combination described above still requires other workarounds, but this is a start...

Comment: You probably want to convert each of the 3 numbers to `sym`, then create a symbolic range. You want the step size to be 1/10, not 0.1 (which is not the same thing, and is the reason for these warnings).

Comment: Also, the point of using `sym` with numeric values is the increased precision over float. Instead of `sym(pi/4)`, do `sym('pi')/4`.

Comment: Adding to Cris' comments; the '1' doesn't generate a warning because octave (i.e. python) knows how to treat this as symbolic. But arbitrary float ranges are treated as floats, with all the machine precision problems these entail. The symbolic package manual says you can convert arbitrary ranges to symbolic (see here: https://octave.sourceforge.io/symbolic/function/@sym/colon.html), maybe you can try this?